Need help in inserting data into a RecyclerView
I have some code where a user can open a popup that allows a user to input 3 things and should insert that into a recyclerView into 3 sorted columns, I managed to get the popup to work but whenever I confirm it my collapsible that contains the recycle view extends but nothing is shown inside
What I'm trying to create
The project for more clarity
Specifically i'm trying to get the code at
        // Initialize the RecyclerView
        itemList = mutableListOf()
        itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(itemList)
        binding.dailyRecycler.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
        binding.dailyRecycler.adapter = itemAdapter

        binding.dayAdd.setOnClickListener {
            showPopup()
        }
    }
    private fun showPopup() {
        val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_calculate, null)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setTitle("Add Item")
            .setPositiveButton("Add") { dialog, which ->
                val itemName = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextItem).text.toString()
                val day = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextDay).text.toString().toInt()
                val price = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextPrice).text.toString().toInt()
                val newItem = Item(itemName, day, price)
                itemList.add(newItem)
                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        builder.show()
    }
}

and this to work
// RecyclerView adapter
class ItemAdapter(private val itemList: MutableList<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {
    // ViewHolder class
    inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val itemNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTextView)
        private val dayTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView)
        private val priceTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView)

        fun bind(item: Item) {
            itemNameTextView.text = item.itemName
            dayTextView.text = item.day.toString()
            priceTextView.text = item.price.toString()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.calculate_items, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = itemList[position]
        holder.bind(currentItem)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = itemList.size
}

calculate_items.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dayTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Day"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>


</LinearLayout>


Could you also add the contents of calculate_items.xml? I can't really find anything wrong with the code you've posted, maybe the XML is the issue or I missed something.

@Fred, here it is, I'm starting to think the error's just a simple mistake

Alright after reviewing the code again the width attribute was the problem, quite embarrassing that I got that wrong for so long
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dayTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Day"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>


</LinearLayout>

